# Argument of Substring

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <pi:PEE xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
    <pi:Employee>
        <pi:Name>NAME ONE</pi:Name>
        <pi:Additional_Information>
            <pi:Strike_1>2017-sept.-14,8 Hours=9570</pi:Strike_1>
            <pi:Strike_2>2017-sept.-11,8 Hours=9570</pi:Strike_2>
        </pi:Additional_Information>
    </pi:Employee>
    <pi:Employee>
        <pi:Name>NAME TWO</pi:Name>
        <pi:Additional_Information>
            <pi:Strike_1>2017-sept.-10,8 Hours=9570</pi:Strike_1>
        </pi:Additional_Information>
    </pi:Employee>
    </pi:PEE>
```

And XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="S1" select="/pi:PEE/pi:Employee/pi:Additional_Information/pi:Strike_1"/>
<xsl:variable name="S2" select="/pi:PEE/pi:Employee/pi:Additional_Information/pi:Strike_2"/>

<xsl:template name="Header">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Copy Data -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Manipulation of Additional Information -->
<xsl:template match="pi:PEE/pi:Employee/pi:Additional_Information">

    <xsl:for-each select="pi:Strike_1">             
    <pi:Time_Off>
        <pi:Code_Name>Unpaid Time Off</pi:Code_Name>
        <pi:Time_Off_Type><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($S1,'=')"/></pi:Time_Off_Type>
        <pi:Time_Off_Date><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($S1,',')"/></pi:Time_Off_Date>
        <pi:Quantity><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($S1,','),' ')"/></pi:Quantity>
        <pi:Unit_of_Time><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before($S1,'='),' ')"/></pi:Unit_of_Time>
    </pi:Time_Off>      
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="pi:Strike_2">             
    <pi:Time_Off>
        <pi:Code_Name>Unpaid Time Off</pi:Code_Name>
        <pi:Time_Off_Type><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($S2,'=')"/></pi:Time_Off_Type>
        <pi:Time_Off_Date><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($S2,',')"/></pi:Time_Off_Date>
        <pi:Quantity><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($S2,','),' ')"/></pi:Quantity>
        <pi:Unit_of_Time><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before($S2,'='),' ')"/></pi:Unit_of_Time>
    </pi:Time_Off>      
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that, i'm getting an error saying: **A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring.**

What happens is that all strings that fall on pi:Strike_1 come together. It should process for each employee, but it just doesn't happen. While pi:Strike_2 will process since only the second employee has pi:Strike_2.

My desired result is:

```
<pi:PEE xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
<pi:Employee>
 <pi:Name>NAME ONE</pi:Name>
 <pi:Time_Off>
   <pi:Code_Name>Unpaid Time Off</pi:Code_Name>
   <pi:Time_Off_Type>9570</pi:Time_Off_Type>
   <pi:Time_Off_Date>2017-09-14</pi:Time_Off_Date>
   <pi:Quantity>8</pi:Quantity>
   <pi:Unit_of_Time>Hours</pi:Unit_of_Time>
  </pi:Time_Off>
  <pi:Time_Off>
   <pi:Code_Name>Unpaid Time Off</pi:Code_Name>
   <pi:Time_Off_Type>9570</pi:Time_Off_Type>
   <pi:Time_Off_Date>2017-09-11</pi:Time_Off_Date>
   <pi:Quantity>8</pi:Quantity>
   <pi:Unit_of_Time>Hours</pi:Unit_of_Time>
   </pi:Time_Off>
 </pi:Employee>
 <pi:Employee>
 <pi:Name>NAME TWO</pi:Name>
 <pi:Time_Off>
   <pi:Code_Name>Unpaid Time Off</pi:Code_Name>
   <pi:Time_Off_Type>9570</pi:Time_Off_Type>
   <pi:Time_Off_Date>2017-09-10</pi:Time_Off_Date>
   <pi:Quantity>8</pi:Quantity>
   <pi:Unit_of_Time>Hours</pi:Unit_of_Time>
  </pi:Time_Off>
  <pi:Time_Off>
 </pi:Employee>
</pi:PEE>
```

How can I resolve this one? What should I do to make the code work? Many thanks!

Comment: Where is your XSLT?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to start this one that's why I don't have yet.

Comment: Start by writing templates to convert the unstructured data in `pi:Additional_Information` into structured XML with a proper date format and properly marked up duration (e.g. 4 hours), whether you can do that directly with `tokenize` or need `xsl:analyze-string` depends on how variable the data can be. Once you have the data converted, it should be easy to compare/match the data with the data in `pi:Time_Off_Correction` and simply adjust the `pi:Code` as needed.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen sorry, I'm not really familiar with tokenize and analyze-string. this will run once every month so there'll be no duplicate of dd (so 20-Sept. and 20-Oct. wont be included in just one file) so I was thinking using dd depending if Strike, Justified or Unjustified, they could be use to map the changes needed in pi:Code

Comment: Then make yourself familiar: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-tokenize, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#analyze-string

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen I edited my question. Can you please suggest what to do? thanks!

Comment: Well, start by posting minimal but complete samples to allow others to reproduce the issue(s). Your current XML snippet has no root element, no namespace declaration. When I try to fix that using information from the XSLT you have posted I get http://xsltransform.net/naZXpXP no errors.

Comment: I made an update. do you think it will be possible to get the desired result? or there is a better way to do this?